# WCF security cross domain

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, transport-security

I have a WCF service hosted in domain `A`. It requires Windows authentication and Anonymous Access has been disabled at the IIS level. Everything works as expected until another domain `B` was introduced. Domain A has absolutely no knowledge of the other domain. So my question is: is there a way to use client configuration hosted in the `domain B` to pass some credentials to the service that will be authenticated against `domain A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you create a trust relationship between Domain A and Domain B you will not be able to use Windows authentication.